# Running "webdriver-manager start" when rubymine(intellij) starts

Tags: javascript, protractor, rubymine

I know I have an option to run "Startup tasks" when I start rubymine. 
I'm working on a Protractor project and I'm trying to start the Selenium( webdriver-manager start) server when I start rubymine, but with no success.
I'm trying to run the command through Bash but with no success. I'm attaching a photo to make it clearer.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is `webdriver-manager` is not in the `PATH` environment variable.

You can install a protractor as npm global package via executing `npm install -g protractor`, then add `npm prefix` into `PATH`,  `npm prefix` is the installation folder of all npm global package. Then you can use `webdriver-manager` in cmd window anywhere.

Keep in mind, the global protractor to supply global `webdriver-manager` in `PATH`.  Your protractor project should has own local protractor as dependency.